# HTML select multiple in Android renders weird?

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to figure out how to code  for proper use through Android phones. Looking at...

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

...it looks nice when selecting options. However, the page always only shows the first option in the list no matter what is selected. Do you know of anything I can do to handle this better?

Comment: Worth Reading: [W3Fools.com](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: I'd suggest that,for user interface element require multiple choices, checkboxes would be the better choice. As for styling a `select`, I'm afraid I have no advice to give. Since they're dependent on the browser/OS more than CSS.

Comment: We are using a jQuery-plugin to present the multiple choices neatly in the Web app. However, the plugin has a minor annoyance in Android and I like the native rendering better on smart phones - hence my question. If it really is that lousy as it seems, we'll stick with the plugin for smart phones as well :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had my coworker load up a test page with a multi-select box.

It appears that on Android (and likely other smartphones) the multi-select elements will only display the first value, since tapping on it brings up (on Android anyways) a dialog to select the elements.

Even using CSS `height` doesn't change the appearance.

Comment: iPhone actually handles it much better. I don't have one here, but I remember seeing something like "1 selected", "2 selected" etc - and much prettier unstyled.